# Preloading images using JQuery- Load images from folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preload

Currently I am using a pretty basic function to pre-load images:

```
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            // Alternatively you could use:
            // (new Image()).src = this;
        });
    }

    // Usage:

    preload([
        'img/imageName.jpg',
        'img/anotherOne.jpg',
        'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

I have a fairly large number of small images I need to pre-load (all far under 1MB when combined), and was wondering if there was a way to do so without declaring each image individually.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user , when are you calling this function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loader-script like [supplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply). This is pretty useful, when loading lots of "smallish" images, because it's much faster.

**Demo**: http://www.typeofnan.com/lab/mxhr-stream/

The loading would look like:

```
supply.listen('image/jpg', function(payload, filename) {
    jQuery('<img>', {
        src: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + payload
    }).appendTo(document.body);;
});

supply.setDealer('/cgi-bin/supply.pl').files({
    images: [
        '/images/foo.jpg',
        '/images/bar.jpg',
        '/images/another.jpg'
    ]
});
```

This example would directly append the newly loaded images to the `document.body`. Of course you could do anything with those in the mime-type-listener.
Admittedly, this also requires to specify each image explicitly but it should be a whole lot faster.

<sup>..and by the way, perhaps the author of [supplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply) will add a ***.jpg** for instance, because that's actually a great idea ;)</sup>

Comment: @andy , anyway its same no of http request from the browser right , how will this improve the performance , can you explani me more...

Comment: @siri: the simple answer is, this will load 100 images with **one** http request, whereas the classic way method (like the OP uses right now) will create 100 http requests. Tons of overhead.

Comment: @andy , how does it finish in one request , any insight will be helpful.

Comment: @siri: well, I posted the github links, its all described there. Short: it uses a little helper script on the server, which concatenates all files and streams those over the wire.

Comment: @jAndy , thats great to hear , this might be really useful for us as we deal with lot of images

Comment: @siri, @andy - Just checked out the demo and am impressed so I think this could be incredibly helpful. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion I have is to consider using CSS sprites, that is put them all in one image and control what is displayed using CSS.

Comment: I'm familiar with using sprites for rollover nav bars, but I must confess I have only read about using them for other purposes. Perhaps I should have mentioned that the images are used for several drop down menus. I understand the positioning method associated with sprites, but since they are spread across several menus it seems like the CSS would be really time consuming.

Comment: @user , are you planning to load the before for performance reasons?? if so when are you planning to call that image

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to load the images for the various menus which are attached to the main navigation to speed up performance (it is looking a bit clunky at the moment). The images are called with click() or focus() depending.

Comment: @user , if you are planning to spend some money there are multiple ways to do it , one suggestion is to use css sprites as the browser makes only request for all the images. You can look at some company's like akamai which caches css,js and images for you , so that the request goes to their nearest servers. You can implement cache headers on the images so that browser caches them and doesn't make subsequent requests , let me know if this info is useful